Built-in Webcam connects to Linux guest in VMWare but doesn't display image correctly
I'm running Kali Linux (deb) on VMWare Workstation 17 Pro. I have my host laptop's (Win10) webcam hooked up to Kali via VMware. On the Kali guest, when I give it a ls /dev/video* I get video0 through video3 as results, meaning the Kali guest knows there is a camera hooked up.
I am testing the camera with cheese to see what it sees, and here is where the issue is. The app/camera does start, but it's mostly a grey box. The top of the image renders a few lines so I can see my ceiling fan, but 95% of the rest of the bottom of the image is grey. The image also flickers here and there, some times showing more of my ceiling. I have the Accelerate 3D Graphics option turned on in VMWare (although I didn't do anything on Kali side, maybe I'm missing something here?).
Any idea how to get this built-in laptop webcam to work properly on the Kali guest OS in VMware?

As we often remind posters, kali=linux is for advanced users that already understand basic Linux very well. Does your camera work properly without VMs, just on a basic Linux install? did you read the [tag:kali-linux] tag you included on your quesiton?
